# Why do JNI active instances prevent GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

## bool PSScavenge::invoke_no_policy()

```
  ...
  if (GCLocker::check_active_before_gc()) {
    return false;
  }
  ...
```

As you can see, if `GCLocker::check_active_before_gc()` is `true`, it doesn't invoke minor GC, which is `PSScavenge::invoke_no_policy()`. Why is it?

## check_active_before_gc()

```
bool GCLocker::check_active_before_gc() {
  assert(SafepointSynchronize::is_at_safepoint(), "only read at safepoint");
  if (is_active() && !_needs_gc) {
    verify_critical_count();
    _needs_gc = true;
    log_debug_jni("Setting _needs_gc.");
  }
  return is_active();
}
```

## is_active()

```
  // Accessors
  static bool is_active() {
    assert(SafepointSynchronize::is_at_safepoint(), "only read at safepoint");
    return is_active_internal();
  }
```

## is_active_internal()

```
  static bool is_active_internal() {
    verify_critical_count();
    return _jni_lock_count > 0;
  }
```

## _jni_lock_count

```
static volatile jint _jni_lock_count;  // number of jni active instances.
```

The `_jni_lock_count` keeps track of the number of threads that are
currently in a critical region.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_jni_lock_count` keeps track of the number of threads that are currently in a critical region.

As [suggested by JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetPrimitiveArrayCritical_ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical), JNI critical functions temporarily disable garbage collection.

> After calling GetPrimitiveArrayCritical, the native code should not
>   run for an extended period of time before it calls
>   ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical. We must treat the code inside this pair
>   of functions as running in a "critical region." **Inside a critical
>   region**, native code must not call other JNI functions, or any system
>   call that may cause the current thread to block and wait for another
>   Java thread. (For example, the current thread must not call read on a
>   stream being written by another Java thread.)
>
> These restrictions make it more likely that the native code will
>   obtain an uncopied version of the array, even if the VM does not
>   support pinning. For example, a **VM may temporarily disable garbage
>   collection** when the native code is holding a pointer to an array
>   obtained via GetPrimitiveArrayCritical.